# Get data from csv file in chunks and insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv

I want to read data from csv file in chunks on laravel i am using this library https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel. My csv file have larage data i am using this code

```
 Excel::filter('chunk')->load('sample.csv')->chunk(50, function($results)
    {
        //insert record in databade in chunks
    },FALSE);
```

above code getting data in chunks but it is taking lot of time time after sometime giving me error `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` .I knew if i will increase `max_excution_time` then this error will not come but it still take lot of time . I dont want to increase `max_excution_time` from `php.ini` file i want after one chunk page it should clear cache or page should refresh or anything else that is better  and that should display status that record `from-to` have been imported

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse` by calling `response()->stream()` method in Laravel

See more:

1. Api :
       https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_stream
2. Tutorial:
       https://medium.com/@barryvdh/streaming-large-csv-files-with-laravel-chunked-queries-4158e484a5a2#.dc49uu24l